# extentLevels for getItemSummaryForItem1

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to put together REST requests to retrieve account, transaction, and statement information for checking (BankData) and credit (CardData) accounts. What puzzles me is that I'm not getting this basic information for such popular banks and Wells Fargo (checking) and Citi Bank (credit).

I'm using the getItemSummaryForItem1 call with these parameters:

CardData:

dex.startLevel: 0

dex.endLevel: 4

BankData

dex.startLevel: 0

dex.endLevel: 2

However, for the checking account I'm not getting statements and for the credit one transactions. For the citi credit card I can get transactions below the statement level however.

Note that I'm getting transactions for checking account and statements (well actually only one) for the credit one.

I also tried various configurations of dex.extentLevels[] with no luck.

Is it possible that yodlee does not support statements for wells fargo checking accounts?

Also, why can't I get credit card transactions at the account level (CardAccountCardTransactionLevel)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yodlee creates statement level transactions only for credit card accounts and not for checking or savings account and hence you are not getting statement for checking but you are getting that for credit card.
Also you should not be using getItemSummaryForItem1 for getting transactions as this API creates a huge load on Yodlee's servers and hence there is another API called executeUserSearchRequest in transactionSearchService which should be used for retrieving transactions.

Below data extent level should be used to only get the account level details.

```
BankData
dex.startLevel: 0
dex.endLevel: 0

CardData:
dex.startLevel: 0
dex.endLevel: 0
```

For cards to get statement level data the dataextent should be

```
CardData:
dex.startLevel: 0
dex.endLevel: 2
```

and for data including statement bill level -

```
CardData:
dex.startLevel: 0
dex.endLevel: 4
```